# How to web-scrape using Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, internet

I'd like to know how to do web scraping using Ubuntu terminal. I've read something about using python with beatifulsoup, urllib, but I was wondering if there is there any way to do it without running a python script?

Let's say I'm searching internet site www.marmara.edu.tr (my university site) and I'd like to get some data, how can i do that by command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the `curl` and text processing utilites like `grep`, `sed` `awk`, etc.

For example:

```
curl https://askubuntu.com/questions/941409 &| grep -Po '(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)'
```

returns the title of your question's page.