# Is there a Desktop Macro Recorder that can send and email or write to a file on failure?

Tags: email

First post so please be kind.  LOL

Request:  I am looking for a Desktop Macro Recorder that I can use to log into the various websites I am responsible for and watch for a specific unique image upon successful login.  If the image does not appear after X seconds, the login is considered a failure.  Upon this failure, either an email is sent to our monitoring server or a file is appended to with the failure.

Currently I am using MacroRecorder (from PhaseExpress) in Windows and it is working to a point.

What is working:

1. I have the automatic login attempts working.
2. Upon successful login (sees a specific image), move to next domain
   and attempt step 1 again.
3. If the image is not detected after x seconds, I currently have the
   Macro set to "End".

The above works fine when I have it running on a spare PC next to me and I can keep an eye on it periodically.

What I am looking for:

Upon hitting the condition in Step 3 above, I would like the recorder/script to either send an email to our "OMG the sky is falling" email address, or append the failure to include the domain checked to a file that we can monitor/parse via our monitoring software.

While I currently have the recorder on Windows, if there is one for Linux, that would be preferred.  I don't see support for this in GNU Xnee.  Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Note:  Yes, our developers are looking into better logging.  The login "front pages" are housed on different servers than the authentication servers.  If there is a desync and the front page is not able to authenticate, there is no current error/log to check.  Until they come up with a solution to better monitor those backend connections and a way to autorepair them, this is what my department is stuck with.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I don't know of any desktop macro app for Ubuntu. I think what you want can be done in [python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/web-scraping-python-tutorial-how-to-scrape-data-from-a-website/) or may be a bash script [based on terminal commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941409/how-to-web-scrape-using-ubuntu-terminal).

Comment: Read `man expect wget`.